# Power BI Index Ranked by Period in Power Query - to create Period ID

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a custom dates table.

I require to create a Period ID per Period.

Creating an Index does not solve the problem as it does not rank the numbers based on the Period.

To give you an example of my data and what my expected results are, see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb308c158a644a2e95b8e6b87e7d8489)

Herewith is sample data:

```
id          MonthInYear
----------- -----------
1           20180100
2           20180100
3           20180100
4           20180100
5           20180100
6           20180200
7           20180200
8           20180200
9           20180200
10          20180200
11          20180200
12          20180200
13          20180200
14          20180300
15          20180300
16          20180300
17          20180300
18          20180300
19          20180300
20          20180300
21          20180300
22          20180300
23          20180300
```

My required results screenshot:

[image: Expected Result]

How do I create a ranked Period ID as per my expected results above in Power Query?

Answer (score 0):

Let your table name is **base_table** and now create a new table **base_table_date_id** using the below code-

```
let
    Source = base_table,
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"MonthInYear", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"id"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"MonthInYear", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
in
    #"Added Index"
```

**Finally** merge your both table **base_table** and **base_table_date_id** into a **new table** using column **MonthInYear**. The new table code will be as below-

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(base_table, {"MonthInYear"}, base_table_date_id, {"MonthInYear"}, "base_table_date_id", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded base_table_date_id" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "base_table_date_id", {"Index"}, {"base_table_date_id.Index"})
in
    #"Expanded base_table_date_id"
```

Her is the final output-

[image]